# WSO2 AS400 PCML ClassCastException

Tags: wso2, ibm-midrange, classcastexception

We're trying to call an AS400 Program on WSO2 5.x using WSO2 PCML Connector.
We've followed instructions described here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/AS400+PCML+Connector

We've downloaded version 9.1 of JT400 driver here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jt400/

As we try to call our program, we're getting this error:

Error occurred while calling the AS400 program: com.ibm.as400.data.PcmlProgram cannot be cast to com.ibm.as400.data.PcmlData {org.wso2.carbon.connector.pcml.AS400CallProgram}
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.as400.data.PcmlProgram cannot be cast to com.ibm.as400.data.PcmlData
    at com.ibm.as400.data.PcmlDocument.generateXPCML(PcmlDocument.java:2400)

We've tried various version of the JT400 drivers and Getting same Exception with different classes.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thnx.

Comment: Can you post your PCML and how you're making the call?

Answer (score 0):

It smells like the mismatch between program and parameter definition in PCML file and input structure in your flow. I suggest you create an RPG program with exact same parameters as in the example, generate PCML for that program and try the example as is - if it works then you can iterate on different parameter types.